# MATLAB: Using the unique function on a cell array of cell arrays

Tags: matlab, text

I have a 1x2 cell array composed of two cells: a 1x3 cell and a 1x4 cell. In particular, for the cell array `a`, I have:

```
a =
  1×2 cell array
    {1×3 cell}    {1×4 cell}

a{1} =
  1×3 cell array
    'A2'    '*'    'A*'

a{2} =
  1×4 cell array
    'A*'    'B'    'AB'    '*'
```

I want to use `unique` on `a` so that I can get out a cell array consisting of *, A*, B, A2, and AB (in no particular order). However, `unique` only operates on a cell array of character vectors (e.g. `unique(a{1})` and `unique(a{2})` work, but `unique({a})` does not). Any suggestions on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
unique([a{:}]);

ans = 

    '*'    'A'    'A*'    'A2'    'AB'    'B'
```

Comment: Thank you. That was so much easier than I was anticipating. I can't believe I didn't think of that (not used to working with cell arrays). Works perfectly.